# How can I see the contents of the mail whose ID I get from mailq command?

Tags: linux, centos, postfix, email-server

I used `mailq` command and I got a line like for example:

```
A705238B4C   603953 Wed May 23 11:09:58  apache@myserver.com
```

So, now I'm wondering is there a way where I can "read" an actual content of the mail by its id `A705238B4C`

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The best way is to make use of the [`postcat`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/postcat) command.

```
postcat -q A705238B4C
```

At least the system I can look at right now, `/var/spool/postfix` is the master directory. Subdirectories of that which matter include `active`, `deferred`, `bounce`, etc. Queued files may be stored using the full file name (`A705238B4C`) or with some level of hashing depth (`A/7/05238B4C`).

Comment: If you do dig down into these directories rather than using `postcat`, the files are part binary but mostly text so `strings` or `hexdump` are the best utilities for reading them depending on which bits you want to see.

Comment: postfix queue files are RFC822 messages. There is no binary data other than in the queue headers used internally by postfix (nexthop data, queue delay etc.)

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [Jeff's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/391998/63361) you can use `postcat` with the `-q` option.

But since Postfix version 2.7, you can also get readable output, by adding the `-h` and/or `-b` options:

> -b     Show body content.
>
> -h     Show message header content.
>
> -q     Search the Postfix queue for the named files instead of taking the names literally.

So this will show you the entire original message with headers and body:

```bash
id=DEDCB58048B
postcat -bh -q $id
```

or to show the headers of all queued messages, you could do something like this:

```bash
mailq | awk '/^[A-F0-9]+\s+/ {print $1}' \
| while read id; do echo $id; postcat -h -q $id; echo; done
```